# Kendo ASP.NET MVC 4 Grid WebAPI

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2, kendo-ui

I currently have a ASP.NET MVC 4 project. Alongside this project I have a separate ASP.NET WebAPI RESTFul service.

I am trying to bind a Kendo Grid to a datasource using the read.URL("path to restful service"). My call is made and the JSON is returned, however it does not bind to the grid.

I cannot use read.Action("Action","Controller") because my webapi controller does not exist within the same project?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at the [remote data binding example](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/remote-data.html) in the Kendo documentation?

Looking at it, your datasource would have define your read method like:

```
transport: {
             read: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
},
```